# importing app to LUIS gets BadArgument: Labels cannot have two overlapping children of the same parent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I just wanted to know what's the reason for this error:

BadArgument: Labels cannot have two overlapping children of the same parent.

while trying to import an app in LUIS using .json file although it's following the required format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the error is saying that you have at least 2 entites label which are using the same word in an utterance.

This is not possible from the UI: 1 word can only be in 1 label.

[image: Entities label]